# The size of particlecloud in PoseArray Message

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I wrote a node that subscribes to amcl particlecloud. I would like to write a callback function that process all the Pose array elements.
How can i get the size of the particlecloud or specifically the number of poses in the PoseArray Message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193634/the-size-of-particlecloud-in-posearray-message/) by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 179 on 2014-09-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[geometry_msgs::PoseArray](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseArray.html) has pose vector type each element represent a particle in case of amcl particlecloud.

```
geometry_msgs::PoseArray poseArray;
int size = poseArray.pose.size();
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on 2014-09-29**:
Thanks it works for me like that:
int size = poseArray.poses.size();

**Comment by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) on 2023-05-19**:
Hi @bvbdort do you know how to increase the size and spread of amcl particles, I am not being able to trigger the plan module for my Ackermann truck and I believe it is due the fact of particles size. I have already changed the parameters but the size seems to keep the same: [AMCL Small particles don't allow Planning](https://answers.ros.org/question/415566/amcl-localization-issues-small-and-concentrated-particle-cloud-for-a-larger-ackermann-steered-robot/)